# Prometheus average over a time period into Grafana table

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I can't seem to figure out the Prometheus query to calculate the single value of, say, average CPU usage per instance over a time period and create the Grafana table out of it:

```
Period: last 3h
Instance A: CPU usage A
Instance B: CPU usage B
```

Simply put, I want to:

1. select a time period in Grafana
2. have Prometheus average the values per instance within that period to a **single value**
3. use that data to populate a Grafana table

Any hints?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To answer myself:

```
avg_over_time(instance:cpu_usage:irate[$__range])
```

Comment: Note that `instance:cpu_usage:irate` is a record rule of mine: `round(100 - (avg without (cpu) (irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{job="nodes",mode="idle"}[2m])) * 100))`

Answer (score 1):

So for example if I would like to get the CPU utilisation , does it mean that this promql will work well?

```
(((count(count(node_cpu_seconds_total{job="vi-prod-node-exporter-ec2-vsat2-spen"}) by (cpu))) - avg(sum by (mode)(rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode='idle',job="vi-prod-node-exporter-ec2-vsat2-spen"}[$__rate_interval])))) * 100) / count(count(node_cpu_seconds_total{job="vi-prod-node-exporter-ec2-vsat2-spen"}) by (cpu))
```